# how to pass in a variable to awk commandline

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm having some trouble passing bash script variables into awk command-line.

Here is pseudocode:

```
for FILE in $INPUT_DIR/*.txt; do
 filename=`echo $FILE | sed -n 's/^.*\(chr[0-9A-Z]*\).*.vcf$/\1/p'`
 OUTPUT_FILE=$OUTPUT_DIR/$filename.snps.txt
 egrep -v "^#" $FILE | awk '{print $2,$4,$5}' > $OUTPUT_FILE
done
```

The final line where I awk the columns, I would like it to be flexible or user input. For example, the user could want columns 6,7,and 8 as well, or column 133 and 138, or column 245 through 248. So how do I custom this so I can have that 'print $2 .... $5' be a user input thing?  For example the user would run this script like : bash script.sh input_dir output_dir [user inputs whatever string of columns], and then I would get those columns in the output. I tried passing it in, but I guess I'm not getting the syntax right.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19075707/951890

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The following test works for me:

```
A="\$3" ; ls -l | awk "{ print $A }"
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to ill-formed input.

Answer (score 20):

With awk, you should declare the variable before use it. This is better than the escape method (awk '{print $'$var'}'):

```
awk -v var1="$col1" -v var2="$col2" 'BEGIN {print var1,var2 }'
```

Where $col1 and $col2 would be the input variables.
Maybe you can try an input variable as string with "$2,$4,$5" and print this variable to get the values (I am not sure if this works)